# Display exploded array

Tags: php, arrays

This is a very noob question. The previous developer has coded the lines as below

```
$a = array("30"=>"ok","40"=>"yes");

$b = "hi";

$c = $a."|".$b;

$d = explode("|",$c);

print_r($d[0]);
```

How can I display the array `array("30"=>"ok","40"=>"yes")`? `print_r($d[0]);` seems to print just `array`

Comment: @IdealBakija: It doesn't work..

Comment: why not just `print_r($d);` ?

Comment: @Kristian: the output will be `Array ( [0] => Array [1] => hi ) ` I would like print `[0]=>Array`

Comment: Have you tried printf?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This prints "`array`" instead of the actual array values is because this line:

```
$c = $a."|".$b;
```

What you're doing is saying:

```
$c = [array] + [string] + [string];
```

which will force `array` to be transformed into a `string`, which is just "array"

if you really want a `|` separated string of array indices, you could theoretically do this:

```
$c = implode("|",$a)."|".$b;
```

But the real best solution here would be to add something to the array *before* exploding the array:

```
$a['50'] = 'hi';
$d = explode("|", $c);
```

Comment: Yes, this is exactly caused by casting array to string, which is a consequence of using concatenation operator. There is no way to restore original array since it was converted to string that way.

Comment: Thanks. Then I should re-code the entire thing.

Comment: yah you should. consider adding the item to the array directly, then exploding. ive edited my answer